# How to use different fonts which are not in google api?

Tags: html, css, google-api

I am able to use all the fonts that are available in google api.
But how to use the fonts like  colorpop and aileron which are not in google api.
how to use these fonts while designing in html and css.

Comment: add the font file to your code and import the font file in the css

Comment: Please read about: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The same you use google fonts. The only difference you need to download locally the font.

Answer (score 0):

First you should download the requre font and after you can import that font to your css code

Answer (score 0):

You can download them locally, place them in your project, then

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: colorpop;
  src: url(colorpop.woff);
}
```

make sure you get your source path right, thats it, easy huh?

then in your css use that font-family

```css
.myclass {
  font-family: colorpop;
}
```